# Excel VBA .Find() error

Tags: vba, excel, find

I have the following piece VBA code, however when I run it I get Infinite MsgBoxes displaying me the same address 4 rows above the Address of ID. I have to stop execution with Ctrl+Break.

I've been trying to get the code to work and it seems to me the error comes from the Find() method. In other versions of my code I get "Method 'Find' of object 'Range' failed. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you.

```
Function CheckFinancials(ID As Integer) As Double
    Dim MyArray(1 To 4) As Integer
    Dim Guide As Range
    Set Guide = Worksheets("Financials").Range(Cells(1, 1),Cells(Worksheets("Financials").UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1))
    Set Guide = Guide.Find(ID)

    MsgBox Guide.Address
```

Comment: Your code, exactly as written, works perfectly for me. It finds the single ID value in the column, displays one MsgBox, and exits. Perhaps the problem is in your calling routine and the infinite loop is there.

Answer (score 0):

Your find miss a lot of parameters (try to record it, you'll see), test this :

```
Function CheckFinancials(ID As Integer) As Double
    Dim MyArray(1 To 4) As Integer
    Dim Guide As Range
    Set Guide = Worksheets("Financials").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Worksheets("Financials").UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1))
    Set Guide = Guide.Find(What:=ID, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    MsgBox Guide.Address
```

Comment: Not all the parameters are required, but it's pot-luck as to what they're set to if you don't specify them. They'll just be set at whatever the last `find` function call had them, whether in code or from the UI dialog box. It's all one set of parms, and one effects the other.